# Render User Submitted HTML in Freeform Notification

Tags: solspace-freeform

I have a form where I need to have a table submitted to Freeform in a text area. This is working correctly, however in the notification the table is not being rendered but is rather outputting raw html, see image.

I've set the notification template to allow html, I've also set the textarea to NOT prevent user html rendering.

Is there soemthing I'm missing?

---

UPDATE - I also set up freeform:entries and this field with the table inside it is outputting the table as entities and not html. Is there some way to get this working?

---

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution to this. I had to wrap the code inside the textarea with {exp:ce_str:ing html_entity_decode}. Now everything works correctly

```
<textarea name="product_requests" style="display:none;">
    {exp:cookie_fav:favourites}
        {if has_favourites}
        {exp:ce_str:ing html_entity_decode}
        <table class="quote-items table table-striped">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Product Id</th>
                    <th>Product Name/Description</th>
                    <th>Quantity</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>

            <tbody>
                {exp:channel:entries channel="product_page" limit="200" entry_id="{favourites_entry_ids}"}
                <tr>
                    <td class="prod_id">{product_id}</td>
                    <td class="prod_name">{title}</td>

                    <td class="prod_quantity">
                        {!--
                            Get Quantity set on Page 1
                        --}
                        {exp:evopost:getpostdata}
                            {ep_quantity_entry_{entry_id}}
                        {/exp:evopost:getpostdata}
                    </td>

                </tr>
                {/exp:channel:entries}
            </tbody>
        </table>
        {/exp:ce_str:ing}

        {/if}

        {if has_favourites == FALSE}
            <p>You haven't chosen any products to request a quote yet.</p>
        {/if}
{/exp:cookie_fav:favourites}
</textarea>
```

Answer (score 0):

Under Admin/Email Settings  try setting default email Format to html

Comment: Just tried that, no change.

Comment: updated my question with new information